# use react-i18next cookies only if user accepts cookies

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next, i18next-browser-languagedetector

I have been using react-i18next for a while and I have recently implemented a Cookie Consent React component. Therefore, I would like to only use cookies in i18next only if the user has accepted them.

The first step for me has been to remove the 'cookie' from the initial configuration:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
const i18nInitialConfig = (): void => {
  i18n
    .use(HttpApi)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    // init i18next
    // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
    .init({
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      whitelist: ['en'],
      preload: ['en'],
      load: 'languageOnly',
      ns: namespaces,
      debug: false,
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
      },
      detection: {
        order: ['querystring'],
        lookupQuerystring: 'lng'
      },
      react: {
        // useSuspense: false,
      }
    });
};
```

However, it seems that removing cookie from detection, etc. does not change anything, I can still see the cookie being set. Is this expected?

My second question is, once the user accepts the cookie, how should I tell react-i18next to use cookies? Should I call init again? I am worried that might have side effects like the user selected language being reset.